# При наведение на ссылку высвечивать элемент на map'е

Tags: html, css, map

Всем здрасти. Есть задача: есть картинка, на ней есть элементы, рядом с картинкой текст, при наведении на определенное слово (в нашем случае помеченные как ссылки) на соседней картинке определенная зона map'а должна изменяться, в основном нужно чтобы поверх картинки появлялись круги определенного цвета или квадраты. У меня пример есть, но он на флеше сделан, мне кажется всяко должен быть какой-то способ сделать это на html+css.

```
<img src="./gif/xdsl.jpg" align="left" width="100" alt="" usemap="#map"/>
<map name="map">    
   <area shape="circle" coords="67, 132, 14" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="38, 340, 9" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="79, 341, 10" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="37, 473, 9" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="78, 473, 8" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="40, 372, 50, 389" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="39, 422, 48, 438" />
</map>
<div>
   <p> <b>Общий индикатор блока:</b></p>
   <p> • <a href="#">зеленый</a> – все датчики блока в норме;</p>
   <p> • <a href="#">мигающий зеленый</a> –установлен шлейф (ближний или дальний) по Е1;</p>
   <p> • <a href="#">красный</a> – произошла одна из аварий</p>
</div>
```

Ну и картинка, как это было на флеше 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пример (для одной части изображения)

Использовал

1. [maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)
2. [imagemap-generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.map').maphilight();
  
  $('#link1').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#area1').mouseover();
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $('#area1').mouseout();
  }).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

ul > li {
  margin: 15px;
}

ul > li > a {
}

ul > li > a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.3.1/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="link1">Индикатор БК-S</a>
  </li>  
</ul>

<img class="map" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G0QY.jpg" width="899" height="687" usemap="#shema">
<map name="shema">

  <area shape="poly" id="area1" coords="75,103,87,103,87,126,62,126,62,103" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" alt="" title="Индикатор БК-S" />  
</map>
```